# I have a question about combination and why some approaches don't work

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Let's say Computer keyboard failures can be attributed to electrical defects or mechanical defects. A repair facility currently has 25 failed keyboards, 6 of which have electrical defects and 19 of which have mechanical defects.

The question asks you If a sample of 5 keyboards is randomly selected, what is the probability that at least 4 of these will have a mechanical defect? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

I tried to solve this using the logic as such

(19! / (4!15!)) * (21! / (1!20!)) which is 3876 * 21 but it isn't correct

because it is larger than (25! / (5!20!))

I looked at the solution and it's the union of (19! / (4!15!)) * (6! / (1!5!)) + (19! / (5!14!))

I understand the logic where you basically add the probability of having only 4 mechanical defect and 5 mechanical defect but why does my method calculate a result that is completely incorrect?

Comment: Your logic appears to be "*Pick four keyboards which have a mechanical defect.  Then, pick one more keyboard from all those that remain.*"  Your error is in not recognizing that this incorrectly applies some sort of significance to whether a particular keyboard was selected during the first step or during the second step.  The outcome where keyboards 1,2,3,4 were selected in the first step as the keyboards with mechanical failures and keyboard 5 selected in the second step as the additional keyboard is supposed to be considered the same as selecting keyboards 1,2,3,5 in step1 and 4 in step2.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: I liked your question; my reply is probably overkill but I rarely see this sort of thing spelled out, so wanted to practice myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices are not independent, so you cannot naively multiply to do the counting.

To get my head round things like this I often imagine labelling the keyboards. Imagine they are labelled $A,B,C,\dots,Y$ and that those with electrical defects are $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ and that the others are the ones with mechanical defects.

Your logic seems to suppose that to pick a valid set of 5 keyboards (i.e. such that at least four have mechanical defects) you need to make two choices):

**1.** Choose 4 of the ones with mechanical defects.

**2.** Choose any keyboard from the remaining 21 keyboards.

I like to imagine a kind of table: Let's say that as you go down the columns, you change choice **1.**, and as you go along the rows, you change choice **2.**. Each 5-set that you count is an entry in the table made from the union of a 4-set from choice **1.** and a 1-set from choice **2.**:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\{G,H,I,J\} \cup \{A\} & \{G,H,I,J\} \cup \{B\} & \{G,H,I,J\} \cup \{C\} & \cdots & \mathbf{\{G,H,I,J\} \cup \{K\}} & \cdots \\
\{G,H,I,K\} \cup \{A\} & \{G,H,I,K\} \cup \{B\} & \{G,H,I,K\} \cup \{C\} & \cdots & \mathbf{\{G,H,I,K\} \cup \{J\}} & \cdots\\
\{G,H,I,L\} \cup \{A\} & \{G,H,I,L\} \cup \{A\} & \{G,H,I,L\} \cup \{A\} & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix}
$$

It should be clear now that you can now end up counting $\{G,H,I,J\} \cup \{K\}$ and then, separately, taking $\{G,H,I,K\} \cup \{J\}$.

*I have counted the valid 5 set $\{G,H,I,J,K\}$ more than once.*

Notice that there are 
$$
\text{No. of columns} =  \binom{21}{1} = \frac{21!}{1!20!}
$$
and
$$
\text{No. of rows} =  \binom{19}{4} = \frac{19!}{4!15!}
$$

***So, if it were the case that*** every valid 5-set appeared exactly once in the matrix, then the total number of 5-sets would be as you computed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really interesting insight to broaden the way I should approach this problem!